# how to get file in file importing using laravel php on server hosting or cloud hosting

Tags: php, laravel-5

When I want to read file and import to database,
In local , can find and read file using following code.

```
$path = $request->file('import_file')->getRealPath();           
$data = Excel::load($path, function($reader) {
   $reader->noHeading();
})->get();
```

But, server hosting or cloud hosting,it shows error as "Cannot read file.File does not exist!".

Please help me how to fix this issue.